# android delay using handler

Tags: android, delay, handler

I want to display a couple of images and add a delay between each image. 
I did this and have no errors in the code but for some reason the app crashes.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageIn);
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    // Those are the only 2 lines I used to make my handler 
    Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();
    handlerTimer.postDelayed((Runnable) this, 20000);
```

Answer (score 34):

You don't say what class hosts the snippet you posted, but I think `handlerTimer.postDelayed((Runnable) this, 20000);` is unlikely to be right.

Try adding an anonymous `Runnable` object such as

```
    handlerTimer.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          // do something             
      }}, 20000);
```

Another thing, `logcat` output is invaluable for getting clues about what is causing a crash.  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html

Comment: if his "this" whatever it is, implements Runnable, there's no problem doing it like he does.

Comment: In addition : to prevent the call to Looper.prepare, you can create the handleTimer this way : 
handleTimer = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());