# Clicking a button automatically after a certain time Android

Tags: android, delay, sleep, wifi-direct

I am a beginner Android developer. I am working on WiFi Direct implementation. My goal is to disconnect one device from another after certain amount of time (Let's say 10 seconds.) after connection occurs. I guess I need to use performClick() and sleep() functions, but I just could not figure out how to use them in my code. Any help would be much appreciated. I put "THINGS TO DO" comment, where I want to do this. Here's the part of my entire code that I have for this:`    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_detail, null);

    Button btn_connect = (Button) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
    btn_connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
            config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
            config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Press back to cancel",
                    "Connecting to :" + device.deviceAddress, true, true

            );
            ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).connect(config);

        }
    });


    Button btn_disconnect = (Button) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_disconnect);
    btn_disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //THINGS TO DO:
                    //i) PASS 10 SECONDS
                    //ii) COME HERE AND MAKE THE PROGRAM CLICK HERE BY ITSELF.
                    ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).disconnect();
                    Log.d("ShowWhenDiscon", "It is disconnected!!!! ");
                }
            });

    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                    // registered apps
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
                }
            });

    return mContentView;
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Handlers.

```
handlerTimer.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
      // do something here

      // You mentioned to click a button, which needs to be run from the UI Thread. 
      // Use runOnUiThread() for this 


  }}, 20000);
```

References:

[runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread)

[handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623578/android-delay-using-handler)