# How to set a delay before changing text in a text view when clicked?

Tags: android

So in my app I want to have some click on a  text view, the text change, have a 3 second delay then have the text change back to the original. Here is what i have so far.

```
        final TextView fact1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fact1);
        fact1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fact1.setText("Text");
            //Delay
            fact1.setText(Original text here, its stored in a text view with the id fact1);

        }
    });
```

How would i go about having a delay inbetween the text view switching?

Comment: SImple Thread.sleep. Use animaton, use timer or check `android:hint` in layout xml

Comment: Any documentation to help?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html
or simpler new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper).postDelayeD(new Runnable ( //change you text here), YOUR_DELAY));
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623578/android-delay-using-handler

Comment: If you just search for a minute found several method...

Answer (score 6):

No reason to create a new `Thread` for this. Just use `postDelayed` on the `TextView`.

```
fact1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String originalText = fact1.getText().toString();
        fact1.setText("New Text");
        fact1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fact1.setText(originalText);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: That is the "correct" answer. Do yourself a favour and do not do any of those non-sense Thread or CountDownTimer. For your simple use case it certainly does not apply. Gerge, I put correct in quotation mark because I wouldn't code it like this as it can potentially create a memory leak.

Comment: @Budius Just to be sure are you referring to the leak of `fact1` and its `Activity`, etc by the `Handler` used internally by `postDelayed`? Typically I'd use my own handler and clear it when I know the `Activity` is moving to background or no longer used but in this case it should only be leaked for roughly the 3 seconds at most right?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I'm referring to. Working in an app with 700K MAU makes me code in an extremely preventive way. There's some really weird stuff that happens out there in the wild. So as general rule I don't do anonymous inner classes.  Even 3 seconds leak count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CountDownTimer` like this :

```
String firstText=mTextField.getText().toString();
  new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {       
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 

           mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " +               millisUntilFinished / 1000); //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext

   } 

public void onFinish() { 
mTextField.setText(firstText); }

 }.start();
```

Comment: How would i get the text back to the original text when i am done? I want it to change for 5 second then go back to what it was. Here is what i have.

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
                Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();
                new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        fact1.setText("Memes"); }
                        public void onFinish() {
                        fact1.setText(); } }.start();
                    }

Comment: Before you start timer change Text and in onFinish method retrive last text.. you can save first text in string variable.

Comment: How would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

you only need to run the code in a thread and call Thread.sleap

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final String[] originalText = {""};
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    originalText[0] = textView.getText().toString();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText("what ever!!");
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(originalText[0]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

by using lambda the code will be much more concise

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final String[] originalText = {""};
        button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                originalText[0] = textView.getText().toString();
                runOnUiThread(() -> textView.setText("what ever!!"));

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(() -> textView.setText(originalText[0]));
            }
        }.start();
    });
```

Comment: WOuld this code change it back to the original text after?

Comment: @George Mulligan answer is better than mine, use it.